# does postgresql suppoert async functions?if so,what is the syntax for it

Tags: postgresql

We have a requirement where the command should reach the  UI even before the  previous transaction is completely executed 
so in need a an async function or a async trigger
or can we have async commit on a particular table in DB??

Comment: sounds more like autonomous commit / xact suspend and resume. and no. but there's dblink.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-function.html) to execute query inside transaction that will not be isolated by it - result will be available outside before commit and even after rollback.

```
create extension dblink;

create table logs (id serial, log text);

create or replace function log_me()
returns void
as $$
begin
  perform dblink('dbname=postgres', $q$ INSERT INTO logs (log) values ('Hello world'); $q$);
  perform pg_sleep(100);
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

select log_me();

--in different session/conenction, while function still waits on pg_sleep - returns 1 row
select * from logs;
```

dblink can also send async query: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-send-query.html if that is what you need.